# How to send keystore in 3rd party desktop application using C# Windows application

Tags: c#

I am facing problem this work only for 2 or 3 days after this send error is access denied but forground windows is focused. and activated ....

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                Process myproc= Process.GetProcessesByName("name").FirstOrDefault();
                if (myproc!= null)
                {
                    var ffCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, myproc.Id);
                    var ffWindows = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, ffCondition);
                    var soWindow = ffWindows.Cast<AutomationElement>().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Current.Name.Contains("title of window "));
                    if (soWindow != null)
                    {

                        var soWindowPattern = soWindow.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern) as WindowPattern;
                        if (soWindowPattern != null)
                        {
                            // Restore window (activating it).
                            soWindowPattern.SetWindowVisualState(WindowVisualState.Normal);

                            Thread.Sleep(100);

                            // Close window.
                            //soWindowPattern.Close();
                            SendKeys.Send("{f1}");
                            //System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{f1}");
                            //string send = System.Windows.Input.Key.F1.ToString();
                            //SendKeys.SendWait(send);
                            var soWindow1 = ffWindows.Cast<AutomationElement>().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Current.Name.Contains("another child window "));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running your app as admin?

Comment: yes i have also tried  this but remaining same

Comment: i also tried sendkeys.send,sendkey.sendwait,     string send = System.Windows.Input.Key.F1.ToString();